# Excel formula to extract number and remove unwanted characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know what Excel formula could be used to remove the * and [LETTER] in a list of cells like below, please? The rows update automatically, so the formula needs to apply to numbers with or without the * and [LETTER].

```
    *23.000*
    16.571
    22.357[d]
    17.125
    12.583
    13.500
    *14.200*
    11.800
    3.500[e]
    6.750
    8.500
    4.900[a]
    5.900
```

The code below removes the [LETTER] but numbers with an asterisk as the first and last character obviously remain.

=TRIM(LEFT(Sheet1!E4,SEARCH("[",Sheet1!E4&"[")-1))

Comment: Like this? `=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!E4,"*",""),SEARCH("[",SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!E4,"*","")&"[")-1))`

Comment: I think that's worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have ***Microsoft-365*** then could try-

```
=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(E4,"*",""),"["),,1)
```

[image]

Comment: ++ Nice. You may want to add TRIM to it `=TRIM(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*",""),"["),,1))`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, if OP has leading spaces then `TRIM()` would be helpful. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: This should also work for a range larger than a single cell: `=TEXTSPLIT(E4:E16,{"*","["," "},,1)`

Comment: @JvdV Very clever trick. I forgot that `TEXTSPLIT()` supports array of delimiter's.